# Hypergeometric function variance

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-function

In a fishing event, a small lake is populated with $75$ trout, among which $25$ are tagged. Each participant is
allowed to capture $5$ fish during the day (the fish are not put back into the lake). For each tagged fish, the participant
wins $\$10$, and for  each non-tagged  fish, the participant wins $\$2$. However, it costs $\$25$ to participate in this event. Find
the expected value and variance of a participant’s net earnings. (Assume for simplicity that there’s only one participant,
so nobody else is fishing at the same time.)

Well, I've found the $E[X]$ to be $-\$1.67$.
Now, I've found the variance for tagged fish caught was of $1.05$ fish.
But I don't know how to get that variance of earning...

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be the number of tagged fish caught. Then the number of untagged fish caught is $5-W$. Net earnings $Y$ are given by 
$$Y=10W+2(5-W)-25=8W-15.$$
It follows that $\text{Var}(Y)=8^2\text{Var}(W)$.

I have not checked the correctness of your calculation of $\text{Var}(W)$.  Note that the unit of variance is fishes$^2$.